# Composition relation between object in active directory schema

Tags: active-directory, schema

I played a bit with AD and schema and was able to made some custom attributes for my users.

For some reason, adding attributes is not enough for me and I would like to know if it is possible to create a new AD object "clearance", with some attributes, and add a 0..* relation betwen user and clearance like this :

[image]

I'm a total noob in Active directory so I wasn't able to find some reliable information about the schema meta-model so ... is it even possible ? If yes, how can I do that ?

To get further I need to make a security claim on this relation and then use it in Dynamic Access Control rules ...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Solution was to mimic already existants attributes : I nneded to create a new auxiliary object and add it as auxiliary class for user. I still don't know how I can use it in Dynamic Access Control.